# why using cv2.calcHist always has an errer "returned NULL without setting an error"

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am using Opencv with python, and come across a question.
When I run the following code:

```py
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0)
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,256,[0,256])
```

An error occurs: **SystemError: <built-in function calcHist> returned NULL without setting an error**
I am confused and can not find the same error in networks, so what's wrong?
Thanks.

PS: I run the same code in both Windows and Ubuntu,and get the same error,so it may not the reason of system ?

Comment: As a general advice around NULL, always check whether your image is empty.

Answer (score 6):

The error message is confusing indeed, but the actual error is simple. Even though you're just using 1 channel, you still need to give a list of histogram sizes and ranges. You've done that for the range, but not for the size.
This should work:

```
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0)
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
```

Wo-Ki anticipates your next problem, as it's unusual to make a histogram of just the blue channel, and you probably want a histogram of the intensity instead. In that case, use the intermediate conversion step as Wo-Ki suggested.

Comment: Your diagnostic and solution are the good ones for me too. "*it's unusual to make a histogram of just the blue channel*", it can be, but not necessarily, e.g. it's common to compute the histogram of the 3 channels individually to [adjust the white balance](https://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/yrgb.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Apparently the ranges [0, 256] have to be same type as img. 
Try

```
hist = cv2.calcHist([img.astype('uint8')],[0],None,[256],[0, 256])
```

instead. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

this question can be solved like this:

```
img = cv2.imread("picture.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hist = cv2.calcHist([gray], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
```